# Unity3D and Microsoft Azure API App to serve json data

Tags: c#, .net, azure, unity-game-engine, mbaas

I'm trying to determine whether it is possible to create an Api app on Azure that can be consumed via HTTP requests on mobile devices with no Azure developed SDK on the client side.(No Unity SDK available and I do not want to use a third party plugin)

I want to communicate with the API, (authenticate, pull resources, etc) with standard http messages over the [www](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) class in unity.

Before I invest a few days in this does anyone know if this is even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with `WWW` or `HttpWebRequest`. Before you do this, try the plugin Azure [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/unityplugins). If it's not what you want, then you can make yours from scratch.